# how to create MVC4 custom login that can be authanticate by facebook

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I want to create custom authentication in MVC4 and log by Facebook. Also how we can use MVC4 default authentication for role management. It create relevant tables when we create internet application but there are no way to manage roles. What is the best and flexible way to create log in?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC4, you can use `OAuthWebSecurity`. You don't even need to use the default user-role default management schema from ASP.NET. 
I've been using for a while and it's flexible enough for me because my applications already had a user-role management, so I didn't need to change my code that already exists, I just needed to add features to allow external authentication by using `OAuthWebSecurity`.

There are some examples like this below

- http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc
- http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2012/09/27/use-mvc-4-and-oauthwebsecurity-to-post-into-your-users-facebook-timeline.aspx
- http://brockallen.com/2012/09/04/using-oauthwebsecurity-without-simplemembership/